# apt: E: Unable to locate package postgresql-client-11

Tags: apt, package-management, postgresql

I have got this:

```
# add-apt-repository main
# add-apt-repository universe
# add-apt-repository restricted
# add-apt-repository multiverse
# apt-get update
# apt-get -y upgrade
# apt-get install -y postgresql-client-11
```

and I get:

> E: Unable to locate package postgresql-client-11

how do I find out how to get version 11.x for this package?

**update:**
I ran this: `apt-cache search postgresql | grep client` the only relevant thing that shows up `postgresql-client-10`...so maybe version 11 is not supported on my ubuntu version? how do I find out?

Comment: You haven't said what release you are running - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=postgresql-client-11 shows it's available for some supported releases but we need your release to provide more

Answer (score 0):

So one solution seems to be forget about the client library and just install:

```
 export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 # apt-get install -yq postgresql
```

but then I get this interactive prompt and it won't accept my answer :(

but I still get:

```
 stderr: pg_dump: server version: 11.2; pg_dump version: 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
 stderr: pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

fml :(

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 is well past EOL; what are you running?